# Delete multiple extended attributes (but not all of them) in one step

Tags: macos, xattr

For example, I have a file with three extended attributes:

```
com.apple.FinderInfo
com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags
com.apple.metadata:kMDItemFinderComment
```

I can delete the first two using

```
xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo file.txt
xattr -d com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags file.txt
```

But I would prefer to not invoke `xattr` multiple times, and to use something like this instead:

```
xattr -d \( com.apple.FinderInfo, com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags \) file.txt
```

```
xattr -d com.apple.FinderInfo -d com.apple.metadata:_kMDItemUserTags file.txt
```

Is it possible somehow?

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm on Mac, but is seems `xattr` is not macOS-specific utility: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html

Comment: The man page you're referring to doesn't describe a command, but the concept of extended attributes. (The Linux tools are `setfattr` and `getfattr`)

Comment: And synopsis for the Mac tool goes `xattr -d [-rsv] attr_name file ...`, where *attr_name* is not an argument to the `-d` option, so `xattr -d this -d that file.txt` also doesn't work. You might be out of luck here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hm, maybe you could run `xattr -d attribute1 -d attribute2 filename`, if `xattr` supports that? That would mean the documentation is a bit wrong, but getopt-based programs often have that problem.

Let's test that:

I don't have MacOS to test, but I got [the original source code of the `xattr` tool](https://github.com/apple-oss-distributions/file_cmds/blob/f8c84000d1f02be159053846a3d730b0290f9614/xattr/xattr.c), and removed all functionality from it so that [my version](https://gist.github.com/marcusmueller/1ed0a235894cc51b86e530ed1e5f1276) compiles on linux and instead prints what it deletes.

Sadly,

```
./xatrr -d foo -d bar foo                                                                                                                                                                               
xatrr: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'bar'
```

Thus, that's not an option.

Well, then:

```bash
for attr in attribute1 attribute2 do; xattr -d ${attr} filename; done
```

is the best I could offer (without relying on more tools).

Comment: Many thanks. `xattr -d attribute1 -d attribute2 filename` doesn't work (see the last example in my question), but `for ... in` is a good workaround.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, is there a practical reason you have wrap `attr` in curly braces? Is it just a personal preference in this particular case?

Comment: @jsx97 it's personal preference. I do prefer it that way, because then I don't have to think when I have two variables names where one is the beginning of the other (and I might not even realize, that longer variable might come from elsewhere).